# Rails where, sort and combine same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sorting, where-clause

I have a model called `extra`. Here how it looks like;

```
#<Extra id: nil, name: nil, price: nil, per: nil, compulsory: nil, online_payment: nil, payment_per_person: nil, is_included: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil>
```

I would like to first sort them by `is_included` where it is true. Then I want to sort where `compulsory` is true, lastly where `compulsory` is false. Then I want to combine them.

Basically, I want to group them because user can save them unordered. Then remove if anyone exists twice.

Shall I do it on the view or before_save callback?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Extra.order('is_included desc, compulsory desc')` will return your desired result and you should never execute SQL queries on view.

Comment: Can you also explain how it works by ordering desc, without putting true or false?

Comment: here's a [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8504/why-are-nulls-sorted-first) which would give you an idea.

In sql true and false values are stored as 1 and 0. So, sorting `is_included` in **descending order** will sort the extras in descending order and then applying sorting on the **resultant** with compulsory attribute in descending order will give you the final result.

The link I shared with you will help you in understanding the sorting of Null values with boolean values.